# How to check that email addresses are valid and separate full name into first and last name in Excel

Tags: excel

I want to import data from Excel to SQL-Server database, but the data from the Excel is not ready to be imported directly into the database, I need to alter the data to fit it into the tables that I have just created.

So before importing data from Excel, I need to remove all the records that has invalid email (some records for example contain '@@').

After that I need to separate the Full name column into Firstname and Lastname (All “full names” are in the format of “Firstname Lastname”, but different separator characters are used.)

[Data from Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwoYm.jpg)

Thanks for any help

Comment: It is generally considered 'good form' to do your own email parsing if you are going to spam.

Comment: What have you tried? Where have you run into problems? Be advised that this is not a free code-writing service but exists to help others with code or functions they are trying to develop.  As such, we expect to see clear cut questions with examples of data, attempted code, actual output, desired output, research efforts to solve the problem, etc.  Please read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld You are right! thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use:
For Firstname:

```
 =TRIM(LEFT(B2,IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("#",B2,1)),FIND("#",B2,1)-1,IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("*",B2,1)),FIND("*",B2,1)-1,IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("|",B2,1)),FIND("|",B2,1)-1,FIND(" ",B2,1)-1)))))
```

For Lastname:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)-IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("#",B2,1)),FIND("#",B2,1),IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("*",B2,1)),FIND("*",B2,1),IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("|",B2,1)),FIND("|",B2,1),FIND(" ",B2,1))))))
```

For email:

`=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(J2," ",""),"@@","@")`

Each in a new column and you can drag the formula down
When finish Copy, Paste Special Values to the corresponding columns